# Why does the "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" error happen?

Tags: tables, errors, columns

I am new to LaTeX, but I have made a table using the code seen below before... I went to edit the table from an old template but received the extra alignment error. Can someone help spot where I went wrong or what I need to do?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{\bf{Calculations for Proctor Compaction}} 
\label{tab:Calculations for Proctor Compaction} 
\begin{tabular}{ C{1.25in} C{0.85in} *4{C{0.75in}}}\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf Property & \bf Unit & \bf Test 1 & \bf Test 2 & \bf Test 3 & \bf Test 4 & \bf Test 5 \\\midrule
\bf Mass of Soil in Oven Can & grams & 43.67 & 67.93 & 52.98 & 38.87 & 66.38  \\\\
\bf Mass of Water in Oven Can & grams & 2.14 & 4.98 & 5.93 & 5.66 & 10.24 \\\\
\bf Moisture Content & [\%] & 4.90 & 7.33 & 11.19 & 14.56 & 15.43  \\\\
\bf Moist Density of Compacted Soil & $\frac{g}{cm^{3}}$ & 1.83 & 1.99 & 2.09 & 2.02 & 1.92 \\\\
\bf Dry Density of Compacted Soil & $\frac{g}{cm^3}$ & 1.74 & 1.85 & 1.88 & 1.76 & 1.66 \\
\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end{tabular}\par
\bigskip

\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have 6 columns in definition of your tabular, but for example this line:

```
\bf Dry Density of Compacted Soil & $\frac{g}{cm^3}$ & 1.74 & 1.85 & 1.88 & 1.76 & 1.66 \\
```

has seven of them. You should probably add one column to your columns definition.

(And please consider changing an obsolete `\bf something` into `\textbf{something}`).

Comment: Or `\bfseries` which would also be appropriate and a parallel of the original switch

Comment: @Au101 +1. Yes, in this case it will be easier to change by replacing `\bf`->`\bfseries` into an editor.

Answer (score 3):

Some comments and observations:

- As Przemysław Scherwentke has already pointed out in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395229/5001), the main problem is that your table actually contains 7 columns, while you've only defined 6.
- Do give some more thought to the way the tabular material is organized. I'd like to suggest that you not use any **bold-facing** at all. Instead, do provide alignment on the decimal markers in the five numeric columns, say, by loading the `siunitx` package and using its `S` column type.
- Do also provide more standard ways to typeset scientific units. Again, if you're willing to load the `siunitx` package, use that package's `\si` macro to typeset units in ways that conform to international standards.
- I'd also like to suggest that you use a `tabularx` environment and allow line-wrapping in the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,caption}
\captionsetup{textfont=bf} % only if needed
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} % amount of whitespace below caption
\caption{Calculations for Proctor Compaction} 
\label{tab:Calculations for Proctor Compaction} 

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
    >{\RaggedRight\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}X 
    c 
    *{5}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
\toprule
Property & Unit & {Test 1} & {Test 2} & {Test 3} & {Test 4} & {Test 5} \\
\midrule
Mass of Soil in Oven Can & grams & 43.67 & 67.93 & 52.98 & 38.87 & 66.38  \\ \addlinespace
Mass of Water in Oven Can & grams & 2.14 & 4.98 & 5.93 & 5.66 & 10.24 \\ \addlinespace
Moisture Content & [\%] & 4.90 & 47.33 & 11.19 & 14.56 & 15.43  \\ \addlinespace
Moist Density of Compacted Soil & \si{\gram\per\cubic\centi\meter} & 1.83 & 1.99 & 2.09 & 2.02 & 1.92 \\ \addlinespace
Dry Density of Compacted Soil & \si{\gram\per\cubic\centi\meter} & 1.74 & 1.85 & 1.88 & 1.76 & 1.66 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```